# Oracle SQL - Get latest value of each column

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table that looks like this:

[image: Sample table]

There are 2 ISIN's in the table (ISIN 1 and 2). If you look at the first row, you'll see that all fields are filled with values. In the second row there is only one field filled, which represents an update of the field (all empty fields didn't changed).

Basically I want the latest value of each field (grouped by ISIN).

[image: Result]

I was thinking of creating a Materialized view, if there is a build-in function or an easy way to achive my result. If there is not, I'll create a pipe function and iterate over the records.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to them.)

Comment: @jarlh I tried to insert a markdown table, but it didn't worked (didn't get formatted). So in the end I just inserted pictures. I'll insert one of these ASCII tables next time.

Comment: That's fine. (It's actually pretty easy, simply write your data in proper columns when editing, highlight it and click `{}`.)

Comment: Hello @JKI , you need to format the table text yourself(ctrl + K). Now everyone who wants to test your something to help you needs to do this: create table... insert into table... and then try to solve your problem....So, to help this people who want to help you you can do it yourself here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18 . Create the test example...

Comment: @JKI if my solution is correct give it a green tick on the left hand side of the answers and mark it as accepted .Others will get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `LAST_VALUE` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT ts,
       id,
       isin,
       value1,
       value2,
       value3,
       value4,
       value5,
       value6
FROM   (
  SELECT ts,
         id,
         isin,
         LAST_VALUE(value1) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY isin ORDER BY ts, id ) AS value1,
         LAST_VALUE(value2) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY isin ORDER BY ts, id ) AS value2,
         LAST_VALUE(value3) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY isin ORDER BY ts, id ) AS value3,
         LAST_VALUE(value4) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY isin ORDER BY ts, id ) AS value4,
         LAST_VALUE(value5) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY isin ORDER BY ts, id ) AS value5,
         LAST_VALUE(value6) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY isin ORDER BY ts, id ) AS value6,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY isin ORDER BY ts DESC, id DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

or, you can use `MAX() ... KEEP ( DENSE_RANK ... )`:

```sql
SELECT MAX(ts) AS ts,
       MAX(id) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ts, id ) AS id,
       isin,
       MAX(value1) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK FIRST
         ORDER BY
           CASE WHEN value1 IS NOT NULL THEN ts END DESC NULLS LAST,
           id DESC
       ) AS value1,
       MAX(value2) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK FIRST
         ORDER BY
           CASE WHEN value2 IS NOT NULL THEN ts END DESC NULLS LAST,
           id DESC
       ) AS value2,
       MAX(value3) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK FIRST
         ORDER BY
           CASE WHEN value3 IS NOT NULL THEN ts END DESC NULLS LAST,
           id DESC
       ) AS value3,
       MAX(value4) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK FIRST
         ORDER BY
           CASE WHEN value4 IS NOT NULL THEN ts END DESC NULLS LAST,
           id DESC
       ) AS value4,
       MAX(value5) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK FIRST
         ORDER BY
           CASE WHEN value5 IS NOT NULL THEN ts END DESC NULLS LAST,
           id DESC
       ) AS value5,
       MAX(value6) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK FIRST
         ORDER BY
           CASE WHEN value6 IS NOT NULL THEN ts END DESC NULLS LAST,
           id DESC
       ) AS value6
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY isin
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ts, id, isin, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6 ) AS
SELECT SYSDATE - 5, 1, 1, 'A',  'B',  'C',  'D',  'E',  'F'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT SYSDATE - 4, 2, 1, NULL, NULL, 'G',  NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT SYSDATE - 3, 3, 1, NULL, 'H',  NULL, NULL, 'I',  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT SYSDATE - 2, 4, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'J',  NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT SYSDATE - 2, 5, 2, 'K',  'L',  'M',  'N',  'O',  'P'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT SYSDATE - 1, 6, 2, NULL, 'Q',  NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT SYSDATE - 0, 7, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'R',  NULL, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> ```
> TS        | ID | ISIN | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | VALUE3 | VALUE4 | VALUE5 | VALUE6
> :-------- | -: | ---: | :----- | :----- | :----- | :----- | :----- | :-----
> 09-NOV-20 |  4 |    1 | A      | H      | G      | J      | I      | F     
> 11-NOV-20 |  7 |    2 | K      | Q      | M      | R      | O      | P
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e6b86a7188424ef902eb13d9e6e35ea4)*

Comment: The Last_Value function was exactly what I was searching for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is it:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(LISTAGG("col1" ,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "col1"),-1,1)as value1,
 SUBSTR(LISTAGG("col2" ,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "col2"),-1,1)as value2,
 SUBSTR(LISTAGG("col3" ,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "col3"),-1,1)as value3,
 SUBSTR(LISTAGG("col4" ,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "col4"),-1,1)as value4,
 SUBSTR(LISTAGG("col5" ,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "col5"),-1,1)as value5,
 SUBSTR(LISTAGG("col6" ,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "col6"),-1,1)as value6

FROM Table1
group by "isin";
```

check:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f02bd/5

Comment: This will not work, because its ordering the individual columns. I suppose it will probably work if you order by id, instead of the individual columns. However I don't know why the LISTAGG function should be used for this. I ended up using @MT0 suggested LAST_VALUE function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the KEEP clause as follows:

```
SELECT ISIN, 
       MAX(VALUE1) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE WHEN VALUE1 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE "TIMESTAMP" END DESC NULLS LAST) AS VALUE1,
       MAX(VALUE2) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE WHEN VALUE2 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE "TIMESTAMP" END DESC NULLS LAST) AS VALUE2,
       ...
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY ISIN;
```